# Oxyclean safe inside the bottle

Tags: labels

I just bought some oxyclean to remove labels from a lot of bottles. What I do to remove the labels is: put the bottles standing in the bucket, fill each bottle with water, and then fill the bucket with water to just above the neck labels and add the oxyclean. I did this because I'm not sure if I should get the oxyclean inside the actual bottle.  No one mentions that you shouldn't, but I read it is not a food safe product.

Should I not worry about this? If not, I can fit more bottle in the bucket.

And what is the proper way to clean the bottles after the oxyclean soak? I just rinsed the inside and out with fresh water a couple of times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you rinse Oxiclean thoroughly, there's no problem getting it in the bottle.  I've been doing it for 15 years and I'm not dead yet!

Comment: That's what i thought, since i haven't read otherwise.  But i just wanted to make sure.

Comment: I'd be more worried about the label glue getting deposited inside the bottle (dissolved into solution, then deposited on a bottle's interior).  So even though it's a pain, I keep the bottles upright.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a great way to clean bottles.  Like Denny said, make sure you rinse very well.  Also, don't make the mistake of thinking that oxyclean is a sanitizer.  You still need to sanitize prior to bottling.  Cheers!